# Can GA4 filter Event names or Event parameters by its name?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

For a website `example.com`, it has 1000+ pages:

- example.com/tiger/english/
- example.com/tiger/french/
- example.com/tiger/ukraine/
- example.com/cat/english/
- example.com/cat/romanian/
- ...

The pattern is simple, `slugname/language` - all pages follow the pattern.

When I was using GA3(UA) tracking, I can just type `/tiger/` to filter all tiger pages, and `/english/` to filter all English pages. It looks like this:

[image]

It's so flexible that I can filter out anything I want on the fly.

However, in GA4, it stops tracking page URLs. I can only send those strings as `custom events`/`event parameters`. How can I filter the topics in GA4? I looked hard but failed to find this magic text box in GA4:

[image: The GA3 text filter]

After some research, I tried to define custom names here:

[image]

And am able to filter by those pre-defined terms.

But there're so many limitations compared to GA3 filters:

1. Only 50 terms can be defined
2. I have to open the admin page and define the terms before making any queries.

Is there any way to use the textbox filter in GA4?

Thanks for any kind of tips/advices.

Comment: it is tracking full page URL by the dimension named `fullPageUrl`

Comment: May I know where can I find the `fullPageUrl` dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this photo help you ?

Follow these steps:

**Reports** - > **Involvement** -> **Events** :

[image]

As an example for my case, I am filtering the dimension equal to "page path" and the value includes "/it-IT"

Sorry, my default language setting is set in Italian, I tried to use translate in English but after applying the filter it will remain in Italian  anyway, I guess it is clear.
If it is not helpful let me know.

[image]

Comment: I don't have `Involvement` under my `Reports`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I found it. Thanks for the information. This works.

Comment: I have done that, sorry for the late. Though the new filter is still not as good as the old version path filter :( There are too many steps to filter pages and it doesn't support custom values (virtual pages)

Comment: @AGamePlayer, remember in GA4, all the custom dimension or custom events should be created first and then after 48 hours you can use them as filter criteria